# Parse.com class dropping using code in IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm developing an app where I'm generating a time table and I stored it on parse, but to regenerate a new time table I need to drop the previous one so how can I do it... is there is any way to drop the parse class programatically.

Answer (score 0):

no you can't drop a class programatically on parse. you have to use the data browser-- https://parse.com/questions/drop-class-programmatically